# What is the best and secured way to implement admin page in a website?

Tags: asp.net, security, web, admin

**Please read the whole question before saying duplicate.There are similar but this is different.**

I have a website that users can post ads. Its written by using ASP.NET. So
If a user post an ad it should go through a review path.( Involving an admin )

eg: User posting an ad. Then admin log to his admin page and review the ad and then give the approve.

I developed it within the same solution file. Currently I put this page in a folder. To access it user have to type

> www.test.com/admin/review.aspx

manually. Because that page is not linked from the main website. And this admin user doesn't have a user account in user account table. Note that whole site is secured with **SSL**.

So admin has to enter a password to enter this page. This password is hard coded( Not getting from the DB ).

So am I using the right approach? Can a hacker attack to this page?

I dont want search engines to index this page. Also what about this hard coded password method? Is it a secure way?
Is it a good way to implement this page in this domain? I have different domains for this website end with .org and .info etc. Can I use such to access my admin page?

Tell me the best and secured approach to do this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the password accessible from the "View page source" available in most browsers? There are tools for easily finding unlinked pages so don't rely on that. Also, I believe testing the password server side is the most secure you can get without encryption but I am no expert on this stuff.

Comment: I assume the site is not using SSL, so the password will be sent in clear text, perhaps you should look at using `ASP.Net Identity`

Comment: you should not store your password as clear string text in production server, you should salt it at least

Comment: @3dd  Whole site is SSL secured.

Comment: @Sylar why not look at `ASP Identity` to do the security management, it should only take a day or two to implement, and the benefits will outweigh the time invested

Answer (score 0):

A hardcoded password is never a good idea:

- Developers of the website will know the admin password for all deployments of the application.
- If the password is discovered by an attacker, it cannot be easily changed.
- Pre-production versions of the app will carry the same admin password as live versions.

The security of the admin page should be be based on the fact the URL is hidden. URLs are hard to keep secret as they're stored in browser and proxy logs, they are emailed, and are leaked in the `referer` header if links are followed or resources are used from other domains (e.g. JQuery).

Hiding the page from search engines is a good idea, however do so via the use of [meta tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en), not `robots.txt`, as robots can be viewed by anybody to determine the location of your secret pages.

Use established security methods to make your admin functionality secure:

- Implement TLS/SSL so all acces is over HTTPS to mitigate Man-In-The-Middle attacks.
- Implement account/IP lockout after a number of incorrect password guesses.
- Use two factor authentication (e.g. Google Authenticator) to mitigate phishing attacks.
- Store passwords in a DB or outsource your authentication to e..g Open ID.
- If storing passwords in your DB, hash and salt them and use a *slow* algorithm such as bcrypt, scrypt or PDKDF2 with the highest number of iterations you can get away with.